# Trasform serverDate in object Date Javascript and Update

Tags: javascript, symfony, momentjs

I use symfony and i get ServerDate like this

```
<script>
var serverDate = '{{ "now"|date()}}';
</script>
```

Then I have this function

```
var update = function(){

    $('.elem-createdAt').each( function(){
        $(this).html(moment($(this).attr('data-time')).from(moment(serverDate)));
    });

};    

$(document).ready(function() {
    update();
    setInterval(update, 60000);
}
```

I use Moment.js. 
I'd like to update every minute my ServerDate without make Ajax Call but I'd like convert serverdate in Object date then every call update function increase time

***UPDATE***

I'd like to do like:

```
$(this).html(moment($(this).attr('data-time')).fromNow());
```

with

```
$(this).html(moment($(this).attr('data-time')).from(moment(serverDate)));
```

where serverDate update every minute

Comment: here is an easy way to use a twig filter, with it you can render the date just as you like http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html

Comment: i can't call `'{{ "now"|date()}}'` inside a file.js, then i have to update `'{{ "now"|date()}}'` every minute

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the javascript date from de php date:

```
<script>
  var serverDate = new Date('<?php echo date(DATE_RFC2822) ?>');
</script>
```

`DATE_RFC2822` is a php constant which provides a date format compatible with javascript date parsing, see:

- http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.types
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: my problem is not the format, i want update serverDate every minute

Comment: Then you will have to request server with an ajax call. Do you use a javascript framework ?

Comment: noI don't use javascript Framework...for know the server time i have to do a Ajax call?

Comment: `$` seems to be jQuery, have a look to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. On course you have to request server every minute from the client.

Comment: i'd like trasform the date retrieve form server ( when i load the page for first time ) in object date javascript

Load page (php) retrive date => pass to Js and transform This in Date.
somethings like this

Comment: yes i use jquery sorry :)

but exampel if i have this date `2014-01-14 10:49:12` I can't create, a date object starting from this date ?

Comment: No, but with a small change, you can parse it: `new Date('2014-01-14T10:49:12')`